# Outlook 2013 shows a metered connection warning on Windows 7; causes Office updates to fail

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have MS Office 2013 on a Windows 7 computer that's showing a metered connection warning in Outlook, also, Office is asking to update itself, and the update invariably fails near the end. During all of this, Outlook is practically unusable. It doesn't fetch any mail and doesn't send anything.

Now, marking a connection as metered/unmetered appears only in Windows 8, so I cannot disable it in any way; also, it actually isn't a metered connection.

The closest to this issue is this thread I've found: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/solved-outlook-2013-and-metered-connection-warning-748217.html but their solution with deleting mapisvc.inf file didn't help.

What else could be causing this and what could I do to solve it?

Comment: Weird. Is your user an Admin?  Try it while logged in as a different user. Does it behave the same way? Before you deleted the mapisvc.inf, did you delete your Outlook profile and create a new one afterwards?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yeah, it's an admin account. The same happens in a standard user account, too.

Comment: Are you sure all previous versions of Outlook have been uninstalled and their registry entries cleaned out?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There haven't been any previous versions of Outlook on the computer, and also it has been about a year now since installing.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating your Outlook mail profile? Have you uninstalling and reinstalling Office/Outlook 2013 yet? What kind of network/Internet connection does the computer have?

Comment: It was both on a wired and a wifi connection. In the end I just gave up and completely reinstalled Office, and this thing hasn't reappeared yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the read-only attribute on all files used by Outlook. This means folders like Windows, Program Files, Users, ... Any folder, where any data accessed by outlook can reside. I had similar problem - after computer crash...

Comment: This answer does not answer the reason the author is getting the notification message they are on a metered connection.  Your problem was unrelated to the author's question.