# Disable Outlook "Metered Connection" warning

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I connect to the internet using 4G. I have set the connection to "metered" in Windows 10.

Unfortunately this means Outlook displays a "metered network" warning and will not download mail until I click "Connect anyway".

This setting appears to be per account so I have to click this for each account before Outlook can download mail. Outlook also appears to silently forget the setting periodically.

I can't find any way to turn this off in Outlook.

I have found two other superuser questions [Settings that reduce Outlook 2016 data usage on a metered connection, while allowing mail](https://superuser.com/questions/995561/settings-that-reduce-outlook-2016-data-usage-on-a-metered-connection-while-allo) and [Outlook 2013 shows a metered connection warning on Windows 7; causes Office updates to fail](https://superuser.com/questions/806286/outlook-2013-shows-a-metered-connection-warning-on-windows-7-causes-office-upda) but these relate to Windows 7 and 8 and don't appear to have been resolved.

To be clear, I would like Windows to consider my connection as "metered" but I would like Outlook to treat it as "unmetered". I do not want to stop using Windows 10 or Outlook.

Appreciate any and all ideas, even if it means writing VBA! Thanks

*[Windows 10 Pro, Office 365, Outlook version 1810 (Monthly channel)]*

Answer (score 0):

The *real* answer to your question is that a metered (`cost=fixed` rather than `unrestricted`) connection prevents Windows updates. And since Windows 10, Microsoft *urgently* wants all users to install all updates all the time. You can find a million complaints about this policy online.

Microsoft is also the maker of Outlook, of course, so this is simply an option they are unwilling to give you because it is not in their best interest, Rather, it is in their best interest for you turn off metered and submit to regular Windows updates on *their* schedule.

I doubt it has escaped Microsoft's notice how different are the two use cases.

If on a metered connection, faced with the prospect of using up GBs of data (in some cases) to DL a Windows update at pay-by-the-Gig prices, most users will understandably opt for postponing that update until they are on an unlimited connection if they have that option.

On the other hand, a majority of users who just *opened Outlook to check their email* will likely be unconcerned about the KB or MB of data used to check their email. First of all the need is more timely, and second the cost is much lower.

I could understand a warning to alert a user who might not realize/remember they're on a metered connection and might not want to spend even the money to DL their email.

But an unconditional warning that can't be turned off? It's impossible for me to believe that's a technical issue, when the coercive motivation is readily available as an explanation in this case.

Answer (score -3):

The metered network is a Windows network setting, not Outlook. Unfortunately, you can’t somehow whitelist Outlook for any or all of your connections or prevent Outlook from requesting the network costs before connecting. To bypass this warning, you have to change the “costs” setting for your network connection so it will no longer be a metered network.

See [Metered network warning and Outlook not connecting automatically](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/metered-network-warning) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

That is kind of auto sense feature by Windows 10. When you are connecting to the Internet via 4G, it detects and makes your connection as the metered network. Your Outlook and OneDrive will go offline mode. 
You can adjust the 'costs' or disable the Metered connection feature completely as shown in below guide for mobile data (3G/4G) connections.
https://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-fix-metered-network-warning-in-outlook-onedrive-in-windows

Comment: this is the exact answer provided by the person in 2018. and still doesn't solve the problem